# How can i remove and unistall completely Cloudflared Packges in ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, xubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

hello I'm new in Linux Ubuntu.
I installed cloudflared by this steps :

```
sudo dpkg -i cloudflare_warp_2021_8_1_1_amd64_a8f66bae8a.deb
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt update
sudo dpkg -i cloudflare_warp_2021_8_1_1_amd64_a8f66bae8a.deb
warp-cli --help
warp-cli register
warp-cli connect
```

I was trying to install cloudflared on linux ubuntu and tried to remove it with some command that searched with result :

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done 
E: The package cloudflared needs to be
reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Now In the upper right corner of the screen I have a "stop" sign, that says:

```
An error occured. Please run Package Manager from the right-click menu
or run apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. 
The error message was: 'Unknown error: '<class 'apt_pkg.Error'>
(E:The package cloudflared needs to be reinstalled, but i can't find an archive for it.)'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies"
```

Now I need to remove completely cloudflared and all the packages in system,
even that STOP icon in upper taskbar.
output after `sudo apt update`is :

```
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [11.4 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB] Hit:3
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease Hit:4
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease Hit:5
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease Fetched 281kB in 3s (102 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done 
5 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Comment: @user535733 here you are :
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [11.4 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Fetched 281 kB in 3s (102 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
5 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

Comment: @user535733 is it ok now?

Comment: @user535733 please help me to fix and resolve my problem!!

Comment: @user535733 i think it's ok now yeah?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall /path/to/your/cloudflare.deb`. Obviously you must use the correct path and filename. Please add the complete input and output to your question.

Comment: @user535733 how can find the correct path and filename?

Comment: You already know the filename: You told it to us in your question above. The path is wherever you saved that file to.

Comment: @user535733 it's not working, i got same output that i did before.

Comment: Please add the complete input and output to your question.